# Can't add Custom.targets file to Xamarin Android project w/Proguard enabled

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, msbuild, proguard

I'm trying to add a Custom.targets file to my Xamarin Android project, which copies some files over from one folder to another before each build.

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <ItemGroup>
      <FilesToCopy Include="$(SolutionDir)shared/Assets/CachePolicies/*.json" />
    </ItemGroup>
    <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
        <Message Text="Copy over CachePolicies" Importance="normal"/>
        <Copy SourceFiles="@(FilesToCopy)" DestinationFolder="$(SolutionDir)android-application/Assets/CachePolicies" />
    </Target>
</Project>
```

This works fine in Debug builds, however in Release builds it's erroring due to Proguard not liking the Custom.targets file.

> /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/External/xbuild/Xamarin/Android/Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(2554,3):
>   error XA4307: Invalid ProGuard configuration file.  Unknown option
>   '

I already tried "fixing" the encoding of the Custom.targets file with the following command:

```
perl -e 's/\xef\xbb\xbf//;' -pi~ Custom.targets
```

...however it's still giving the same error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that I had copy/pasted my proguard.cfg file when creating my Custom.targets file, and had forgotten to change the build action from ProguardConfiguration to None.

Comment: Don't forget to accept  your answer, which will help more people .